# Discrepancy in Squaring a number stored in double format

Tags: java, math, double, pow

I am trying to square a number x but there seems to be some discrepancy in precision while squaring it using Math.pow() and squaring it using multiplication.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long x = 1250075001;
        System.out.println(x*x);
        System.out.println(Math.pow((double)x,2.0));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> 1562687508125150001 
> 1.56268750812514995E18

The deviation is both the results in shown in bold

15626875081251**50001** 
1.5626875081251**4995**E18

I am not an expert in double arithmetic and how Math.pow() function works. 
I tried reading some online articles on IEEE double standard and Math.pow() but it didn't help and that's why I came to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: First one is true integer math, with floats/doubles you loose precision since the number is longer than double precision of ~15 decimal digits, even if you write `(double) x * (double) x`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You know enough to know that f.p. arithmetic is imprecise don't you?

Answer (score 0):

The number `1250075001`, as a `double`, is stored as (sign ignored)

```
Exponent   Mantissa (52 bits)
  +30      (1.)0010101000001010100001011110010000000000000000000000
```

Note that this *exactly* represents `1250075001` since this integer still fits within 53 bits in binary form.

When you square this number, the exponent doubles to `60`, and the mantissa is squared to become `(1.)010110101111110010000000001001011000101111010110101100110001` (60 bits). As the mantissa must fit within 52 bits, the last 8 bits are truncated. Thus, you lose `001100012 = 49` from the true result i.e., instead of `1562687508125150001`, you'll get `1562687508125149952` which is stored as

```
Exponent   Mantissa (52 bits)
  +60      (1.)0101101011111100100000000010010110001011110101101011
```

You can play with binary converter/calculator [here](https://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-calculator/), or with demonstration of IEEE 754 standard [here](http://weitz.de/ieee/).